# Incrementing a variable by condition

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong? I would like to use count as a global variable.

```
count = 0 
card = low

def running_count ():
    if card == low:
        count = count+1
    elif card == mid:
        count = count
    elif card == high:
        count = count-1

print(count)
```

I get 0 as the result

Comment: I see no function call.

Comment: You need to declare that it's the global variable inside `running_count`: `global count`

Comment: call the func like `this_func()` for ex

Comment: or `low = 'low'` could also work, i guess

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using global variables where possible.

card should be a string, which you compare to a string inside your function.

You need to call the function you have defined so it gets exectued.

This is an example of how you could do it.

```py
count = 0 
card = 'low'

def running_count(count, card):
    if card == 'low':
        count = count+1
    elif card == 'mid':
        count = count
    elif card == 'high':
        count = count-1
    return count
    
count = running_count(count, card)
print(count)
```

Also you don't really need

```
elif card == 'mid':
   count = count
```

since you don't change the value of count, you could simply skip this step, because all value besides 'low' and 'high' don't change count.

I hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much. I am a novice so this explanation is was increedibly helpful.

Comment: now I need to figure out how to store the count for continuous updates. While always starting the count at zero.

my ultimate goal is to create a separate application with a "low" , "mid", and "high" button

Comment: @danew you could try looking into while loops. Then everytime you press a button, your function gets executed. The while loop keeps your program going and you can keep changing count while your program is running. If I understood you correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0 
card = 'low'

def running_count(card):
  global count
  if card == 'low':
      count = count+1
  elif card == 'mid':
      count = count
  elif card == 'high':
      count = count-1

running_count(card)
print(count)
#1
running_count(card)
print(count)
#2
```

But it safer to not use global if you don't have to.